# How to push third-party realtime API data consumed pushed to SQS using Lambda function and Python?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework

I have a third-party realtime API that must be consumed pushed to SQS and later the SQS data must be put into DynamoDB. Is it possible? Any suggestion or reference must be appreciated. Mentioning that i'm fully new to SQS and DynamoDB. Consider me i have zero idea about SQS and DynamoDB. Passionate about creating AWS server-less application.

Comment: Sorry, this question is too broad. Please see https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and finally got boto3 SQS documentation ([click here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html)) that must meet your expectation I believe.
A sample example i can show you here.

```
    import boto3

    # Create SQS client
    sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
    queue_url = 'YOUR SQS URL HERE'

    # Send message to SQS queue
    response = sqs.send_message(
        QueueUrl=queue_url,
        DelaySeconds=10,
        MessageAttributes={
            'Author': {
                'DataType': 'String',
                'StringValue': 'SOME NAME'
            }
        },
        MessageBody=(
            'YOUR MESSAGE DESCRIPTION HERE'
        )
    )

    print(response['MessageId'])
```